# How to efficiently store schedular dates?

Tags: database, algorithm, scheduler

For example I have:

1. **Start date**  (1 Column)
2. **End date**    (1 Column)
3. **Weekday**: mon, tues, wed, thur, fri, sat, sun (1 Column)

How do I define the week so I can store the above data in a 3 field in the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "Week"? Do you mean that you can set the scheduler to run once on each day?

Comment: The week can be , mon and tues or more selected...But i want this(Mon and tues) store 1 row and 1 colunm in database

Comment: @user1865039 Could you explain how the scheduler works..? Could you provide an example..? How do you plan to use the data? 
You could store all this information in a single table cell/field but then you would have to spend time splitting the data.

Comment: Just use a separate column for each day of the week..

Comment: I plan have column StartDate, EndDate, and Week (Mon, tues, wed, thurs, fri, sat, sun) in one row.

Comment: @user1865039 So you are going to now store each in a separate DB field? Then kindly re-edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a processing perceptive, storing those 3 fields in a single cell is not recommended.
You would have to go through unnecessary overhead to encode and decode the data while writing to and reading from the table and also would need to perform additional data-type conversions!

You could try something like : ,,
Where  : 124 for Monday, Tuesday and Thursday. But as discussed above, it is not the right way to go about it..

Ideally you have 3 columns for each item and store the weekdays in a number of formats:

1. `<weekday_list_to_run_the _scheduled_tasks>`: Where we encode `Monday,
   Tuesday and Thursday` as `124`. Requires the most processing.
2. Good-old AND-ing:
   Say we store `<weekday_list_to_run_the _scheduled_tasks> = Monday-X-X-Thursday-Fri-X-Sunday` as `1001101`. 
   Then through 7 AND-ing operations we find the days on which the
   schedule should run.

Eg.

```
IF (<weekday_list_to_run_the _scheduled_tasks> AND 1000000) == 1 THEN 
     //Monday is set. 
END IF
```